# php income breakdown report problems

Tags: php, math

I have to create a report which breaksdown membership fees over the fiscal years.

Fiscal year starts on the 31 July
membership length is 1 or 2 years.

I would like to pro-rate the membership to determine how much of their dues belong in which fiscal year.

for example, a 1 year membership depending on when the member started, would span 2 fiscal years.

Ie 365 days, 50 days in fiscal year 1 and 315 in the second fiscal year. So the total would be (Dues/365) x 50 for year 1 and (Dues/365) year 2.

How could I reflect that in my report?

Thanks!

Edit:

this is an actual example form the current membership. Fiscal year is on the 31 of July

Member 1, dues $50, received 09/10/2009, days 730,
Breakdown Fy2010 20.82, fy2011 25.00, fy2012 4.18

Comment: All I can think, "A train is going from Cleveland to Ohio at 35 miles per hour, another train leaves from Boston and is travelling at 200 miles per hour. At what point does the inevitable explosion result in the undoing of all society as we know it?"

Comment: Hi,
It's quite hard to follow your logic... do you mean to say that you pro-rate the membership fee?  Where does the 50 days come in otherwise?

Comment: to andy, yes the membership is pro-rated. I was forgetting the word

Comment: @JonYork, you have the formula for figuring out what you need, so what is your question?

Comment: How to do it in php considering that the fiscal year is on july 31

Comment: @JonYork, I still don't understand what your question is.  Provide data, and expected output.

Comment: See Edit. I gave an actual example from the current books

Comment: Some businesses pay real money to developers to solve questions such as these...

Comment: Jon, are you just trying to figure out the difference between the membership date and the end of the fiscal year in days?

Comment: @Brian, I think so.

 I figure if I have that, I could multiply it by (dues/membership length) and it would give me how much is used up in the first year, and put the remainder in the next year.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jon,
Here's a routine to get the next invoice date - http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php#103196 which you could modify to get the next two fiscal year end dates, since they always end on the same date, but different years.

Combine that with a date diff, such as the function here http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-diff.php and you should be able to calculate how much time is left in each fiscal year.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Brian Hoover who led me to the proper information.

I wish to display the code for others to see just how you can pro-rate things (it is tricky!)
If you have any suggestions on making the code cleaner, please advise. I am just a newbie.

```
<?php 

//setup of the dates and values to play with

$now = $row->Membership_Date;
$membership_date = strtotime($now);
$fy2010 = strtotime("2010-07-31");
$fy2011 = strtotime("2011-07-31");
$fy2012 = strtotime("2012-07-31");
$fy2013 = strtotime("2013-07-31");
$fy2014 = strtotime("2014-07-31");

//doing the math to determine time span in unix timecode

$datedifffy2010 = $fy2010 - $membership_date;
$datedifffy2011 = $fy2011 - $membership_date;
$datedifffy2012 = $fy2012 - $membership_date;
$datedifffy2013 = $fy2013 - $membership_date;
$datedifffy2014 = $fy2014 - $membership_date;

//doing the math to transform it into full days

$fulldays2010 = floor($datedifffy2010/(60*60*24));
$fulldays2011 = floor($datedifffy2011/(60*60*24));
$fulldays2012 = floor($datedifffy2012/(60*60*24));
$fulldays2013 = floor($datedifffy2013/(60*60*24));
$fulldays2014 = floor($datedifffy2014/(60*60*24));

//Some values come back as negative, so we are making those zero

if ($fulldays2010 <= 0)
{
    $fulldays2010 = 0;  
};

if ($fulldays2011 <= 0)
{
    $fulldays2011 = 0;  
};

if ($fulldays2012 <= 0)
{
    $fulldays2012 = 0;  
};

if ($fulldays2013 <= 0)
{
    $fulldays2013 = 0;  
};

if ($fulldays2014 <= 0)
{
    $fulldays2014 = 0;  
};

//arithmetic to determine how many days belong to which fiscal year

if ($row->Membership_Length == 2)
{
$fy11remainder = 730 - $fulldays2010;
if ($fy11remainder >= 365) $fy11remainder = 365;
$fy12remainder = 730 - $fy11remainder - $fulldays2010;
if ($fy12remainder >= 365) $fy12remainder = 365;
$fy13remainder = 730 - $fy12remainder - $fy11remainder - $fulldays2010;
if ($fy13remainder >= 365) $fy13remainder = 365;
$fy14remainder = 730 - $fy13remainder - $fy12remainder - $fy11remainder - $fulldays2010;
}
else
{
$fy11remainder = 365 - $fulldays2010;
if ($fy11remainder >= 365) $fy11remainder = 365;
$fy12remainder = 365 - $fy11remainder - $fulldays2010;
if ($fy12remainder >= 365) $fy12remainder = 365;
$fy13remainder = 365 - $fy12remainder - $fy11remainder - $fulldays2010;
if ($fy13remainder >= 365) $fy13remainder = 365;
$fy14remainder = 365 - $fy13remainder - $fy12remainder - $fy11remainder - $fulldays2010;

};

//determining the mill rate for days (our organization has discounts for 2 year memberships, and different types of memberships have different prices

if ($length == 2)
{
    $income = $row->Dues_Paid;
    $daily_income = $income / 730;
}
else
{
    $income = $row->Dues_Paid;
    $daily_income = $income / 365;
};

//Mutiplying days by the mill rate for that specific entry or member

$fy10inc = $fulldays2010 * $daily_income;
$fy11inc = $fy11remainder * $daily_income;
$fy12inc = $fy12remainder * $daily_income;
$fy13inc = $fy13remainder * $daily_income;
$fy14inc = $fy14remainder * $daily_income;

//display pro-rate for fiscal year

echo $fy10inc;


?>
```